# Fluid emerging from random part rather than flow object - Blender 2.82

Tags: eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I was trying fluid simulation in blender 2.82, but the fluid seems to be coming from some invisible object inside the domain rather than from the inflow object that I specified, The domain boundaries seems to be working fine, but the gravity is also similarly inverted.

The flow starts from a surface almost identical to the flow object, but from the other side of the domain, and fluid seems to act as if gravity is inverted.[image]

Is this any configuration I missed (although no videos on mantaflow does say to do anything different than what I did), or is it a bug in mantaflow.

The blend file is :

[image]